# Why is the JSON returning as nil for everything besides latitude and longitude?

Tags: json, swift, tableview, decodable

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var tableview: UITableView!
var weatherList: [weatherJSON] = []


func downloadJSON() {
    let jsonUrlString = "https://api.darksky.net/forecast/59c6b6b7efd5c3fc0f617338cfae6c48/40.7127,-74.0059"
    guard let url = URL(string: jsonUrlString) else {return}
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, err) in
        guard let data = data else {return}

        do {
            let JSON = try JSONDecoder().decode(weatherJSON.self, from: data)
            self.weatherList.append(JSON)
            print(self.weatherList)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.tableview.reloadData()
            }
        } catch let jsonErr {
            print("Error serializing json", jsonErr)
        }

        }.resume()
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    downloadJSON()

}
}


extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return weatherList.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! countryCell


cell.nameLabel?.text = "\(String(describing: weatherList[indexPath.row].latitude))"


    return cell
}
}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate {
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "segue1", sender: nil)
}
}
```

Edit: I called the JSON data successfully by using string interpolation -

cell.nameLabel?.text = "(String(describing: weatherList[indexPath.row].latitude))"

but now the only information returning anything but nil in my call is latitude and longitude. Why is the only thing returning from my JSON call successfully nil? Am I calling something incorrectly? Thank you for all your help so far. If I should make a new post, please let me know. I think that this is on the same topic though, as it's pretty much the same idea as the original posting by me yesterday.

Stackoverflow itself won't let me post without adding more text, but because I've already said everything I need to say, this is just filler.

Comment: Where's your attempt to update your `weatherList` property with the loaded data?

Comment: (I'm a newb, so I know I'm asking a question that is very simple, but it is not something I know how to do.) How would one do that?

Comment: You are not saving your JSON result of the request in the weatherList[]. You need to do that. I explain in my answer @Westopher

Comment: This cannot work anyway. `JSON` is a single object and you declared `weatherList` as an array. The answer depends on the structure of the `weatherJSON` struct. And which information – there are many – do you want to display? By the way, struct names are supposed to begin with an uppercase letter.

Comment: @vadian I literally just want to get any information I can from the parsing of this json into my tableview. Yes, my structs are capitalized in my model; I will update that in my code, thank you.

How would you make json append properly into weatherList then? What does that code look like?

Comment: The *cannot assign* error is easy to fix, just create a string from the result: `String(weatherList[indexPath.row].currently!.cloudCover)`. You should declare `currently` as non-optional to avoid the force unwrapping. But you still have the problem that your data source array contains only one item because the root object of the weather JSON is a dictionary.

Comment: That was my first thought as well! Great minds. But, I do that and I get this error: "Cannot invoke initializer for type 'String' with an argument list of type '(Float?)'" :-/

Comment: Oh, `cloudCover` is optional, too. `String(weatherList[indexPath.row].currently!.cloudCover!)`. The weather APIs send reliable data, declare the properties non-optional as much as possible.

Comment: When I make JSON an array, it gives me this error: "Cannot convert value of type 'weatherJSON' to specified type 'Array''

let JSON: Array = try JSONDecoder().decode(weatherJSON.self, from: data)

Comment: You cannot *make* an array from a single object by annotating the type. Without knowing the contents of `weatherJSON` it's rather impossible to answer the question.

Comment: I've got the model file with all of the structs laid out and initialized in another file in the same project in Xcode.

Comment: Once again, without knowing the structs and what you want to display the question cannot be answered satisfactorily.

Answer (score -1):

In order to have better/cleaner code, maybe you want to separate your API call in a function (maybe `func makeRequest()` or something ) in order to only call that function in your `viewDidLoad.`

You have

```
var weatherList: [weatherJSON] = []
```

That is a list with weatherJSON objects that you want the table to show, but the problem is in your request, where you are reloading the data in the table but you are not saving your JSON response in your `weatherList`.
You should first save the JSON response in your variable `weatherList` or append the results to that array. Doing it so,you will be able to populate your table when : `cell.nameLabel?.text = weatherList[indexPath.row]`

Also, you need to add the property of the weatherlist object you want to show.
something like `weatherList[indexPath.row].name` or the name of the property that the object has.

Also, I recommend using some library to make HTTP requests like AlamoFire and SwiftyJson to map your JSON response to your object.

Using the libraries I mentioned, your entire API call and table functions can be like this
        func getWeather(){

```
    let url: String = "http://example.com/api/weather/"

    AFWrapper.requestGETURL(url, success: {
        (JSONResponse) -> Void in

        for item in JSONResponse{
            let weatherList = [WeatherList(fromJson: item.1)]

            for weather in weatherList {
                self. weatherList.append(weather)
            }
        }

        self.tableView.reloadData()
    })
    {
        (error) -> Void in
        print("Error \(error)")
    }




}
```

And in your table func:

```
cell.nameLabel.text =  self.weatherList[indexPath.row].name
```

That can be achieved with an AlamoFireWrapper Class to make a post and a get request like this:
AlamoFireWrapper.swift

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON

class AFWrapper: NSObject {
    class func requestGETURL(_ strURL: String, success:@escaping (JSON) -> Void, failure:@escaping (Error) -> Void) {
        Alamofire.request(strURL).responseJSON { (responseObject) -> Void in



            if responseObject.result.isSuccess {
                let resJson = JSON(responseObject.result.value!)
                success(resJson)
            }
            if responseObject.result.isFailure {
                let error : Error = responseObject.result.error!
                failure(error)
            }
        }
    }

    class func requestPOSTURL(_ strURL : String, params : [String : AnyObject]?, headers : [String : String]?, success:@escaping (JSON) -> Void, failure:@escaping (Error) -> Void){

        Alamofire.request(strURL, method: .post, parameters: params, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers).responseJSON { (responseObject) -> Void in



            if responseObject.result.isSuccess {
                let resJson = JSON(responseObject.result.value!)
                success(resJson)
            }
            if responseObject.result.isFailure {
                let error : Error = responseObject.result.error!
                failure(error)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Gabo, thank you for showing me this. I don't know why one would use Alamofire now that you can use decodable though? Decodable is much less code, and isn't external, so it is much more stable over time, yes? I don't mean to be contrarian, and I appreciate your answer, however, I'm genuinely confused as to what the advantage is of using Alamofire if you can get the JSON without using it?

Comment: Also, I'm just learning, so I'm literally just trying to get my JSON to populate into a tableview. That's all I want to do; baby steps at first...

Comment: Downvoted, you should not recommend libraries that are easily replaceable with apple libraries unless they offer positive benefits over the apple equivalent. Alamofire is very redundant with URLSession and SwiftyJSON is made redundant through Codable.

Comment: Thank you @SeanLintern88 ; I am relatively new to coding, but I think the same thing. Can you look at the problem above and help me with this solution? I really want to successfully knock this bad-boy out using only URLSession and Codable. Thanks!